# Installing neo4j at Ubuntu, certificate has expired

Tags: neo4j

I try to install according to

[Neo4j Debain Package installation](http://debian.neo4j.org/?_ga=2.72181008.2022796163.1531108767-1593472129.1531108767)

But get this error message which says that the certificate has expired:

```
   wget -O - https://debian.neo4j.org/neotechnology.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -

--2018-07-09 06:21:45--  https://debian.neo4j.org/neotechnology.gpg.key
Slår upp debian.neo4j.org (debian.neo4j.org)... 52.0.233.188
Ansluter till debian.neo4j.org (debian.neo4j.org)|52.0.233.188|:443... ansluten.
FEL: kan inte validera certifikatet för debian.neo4j.org, utfärdat av "CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2,OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/,O=GoDaddy.com\\, Inc.,L=Scottsdale,ST=Arizona,C=US":
  Utfärdat certifikat har gått ut.
För att ansluta till debian.neo4j.org på osäkert sätt, använd "--no-check-certificate".
gpg: hittade ingen giltig OpenPGP-data.
```

How do I manage this?

Answer (score 0):

Works now so probably the certificate was updated by neo4j